# How to send emails from multiple domains

Tags: email, domain

I have a number of Drupal websites running under several different domains. These websites must be able to send emails to users. Furthermore, I have a Zimbra mail server running. In Drupal I can either choose to send emails via SMTP or sendmail.

Actually, I'd rather use the SMTP option so that I utilize my mail server's DKIM setup. But I can't really make it work. I just got my mail server up and running today, so I'm not yet familiar with it.

But what is the best way to handle outgoing emails from multiple domains? Is it using Zimbras MTA or should I rather try to configure sendmail?
It is of course a requirement that DKIM support must be provided so that my emails are not sorted out as spam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it is better to let Zimbra manage domains. One important point is to have proper DNS record for each domains. Also if you have idea to use SSL/TLS to have certificate and key for this domain (as well as CA intermediate certificates)

For more details you can check [official Zimbra wiki](https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Managing_Domains)